# How to know weather ETH or some token like USDT is transfered in smart contract transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ether

From last two weeks I am stuck on, I want to know in smart contract transaction either ETH is transfered or some token like USDT below is the JSON of transaction hash.
I am working with DotNet core RPC.

```
{
    "transactionHash": "0xb93a82f4ceed6c77b8b421a839ffffc3b1d1c2c065a3e3382d815c13a6a547e3",
    "transactionIndex": "0x91",
    "blockHash": "0xbd20bcf8a9c1433d7016f3b518d3fdc9a33e534e820e2a98f9d67ae4c614b7e6",
    "blockNumber": "0x896d0f",
    "cumulativeGasUsed": "0x794171",
    "gasUsed": "0x14489",
    "contractAddress": null,
    "status": "0x1",
    "logs": [{
            "address": "0xdf61a8ca6a3a0792f7cac13d6cf9e985cff5930d",
            "topics": ["0x26f502fee81fb474ff4f7459e3616105936e3b70b78e9fa2225a512444f4afca"],
            "data": "0x00000000000000000000000084c00096e7652a8341d075d8cde38715fd2a977c  757234ff4c809d89eeac30d68291f4d3d650fbc62f3b098e171cb1e5a8acaf85 000000000000000000000000a5f3a8ac8e2c387d0f87f1231509668dfff1d5ac 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000890063b226a8 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "blockNumber": "0x896d0f",
            "transactionHash": "0xb93a82f4ceed6c77b8b421a839ffffc3b1d1c2c065a3e3382d815c13a6a547e3",
            "transactionIndex": "0x91",
            "blockHash": "0xbd20bcf8a9c1433d7016f3b518d3fdc9a33e534e820e2a98f9d67ae4c614b7e6",
            "logIndex": "0x79",
            "removed": false
        }, {
            "address": "0xdf61a8ca6a3a0792f7cac13d6cf9e985cff5930d",
            "topics": ["0x34cc068f12a8d0a649a7f91f1342bcc33b312d9b31f96577df5dbc097caec52d"],
            "data": "0x757234ff4c809d89eeac30d68291f4d3d650fbc62f3b098e171cb1e5a8acaf85000000000000000000000000a5f3a8ac8e2c387d0f87f1231509668dfff1d5ac0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000890063b226a80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "blockNumber": "0x896d0f",
            "transactionHash": "0xb93a82f4ceed6c77b8b421a839ffffc3b1d1c2c065a3e3382d815c13a6a547e3",
            "transactionIndex": "0x91",
            "blockHash": "0xbd20bcf8a9c1433d7016f3b518d3fdc9a33e534e820e2a98f9d67ae4c614b7e6",
            "logIndex": "0x7a",
            "removed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

In this transaction ETH transfers.

Comment: i don't understand your question. Every transaction have a section call value which indicates how much eth was sent if the value is 0 then no eth was sent and vice versa

Comment: @haxer Yes youare right, but in case of smart contract if ETH are transfered value is still 0. I want to know if ETH are transfer of a token like USDT in smart contract transaction

Comment: @haxerl this is sample transaction in with USDT transferes with same contract.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfcde4d7b42c694bb8ad3b50ef2a6c60806981db35d34c5e3859b1a2387bcfffa

Comment: For an ERC20 token you have to look for `Transfer()` event.

Comment: I am reading a block and its transactions. If I get a smart contract transaction there I want to know that the transfer value is ETH or some Token.

Comment: @TalhaTalha The ERC20 Transfer events appear in the transaction's receipt. Transfer of ethers don't have any event generated, to track balances you have to trace the execution of transactions in a block.